# How to implement ng-change for custom directive for select list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-options

My directive usage code

```
       <input-select ng-model="someModel" ng-change="someFunction()"
   options="countries"></input-select>
```

My directive code

```
 .directive('inputSelect', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'someTemplate.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            ngChange: '='
        }
    };
});
```

My directive template

```
    <select 
            ng-model="ngModel" ng-init="ngModel "
            ng-options="option[optionId] as option[optionName] for option in options"
            ng-change="ngChange">
    </select>
```

So, when the selected item is changed, the function `someFunction()` is getting called for infinite times (although the change is done once), what should be changed in order to make sure `someFunction()` get's called only once ( `someFunction()` is a function in the scope of the controller in which the directive is being used )

[ I did try using `&` and `@` for the scope type of ngChange, `somefunction()` doesn't get fired if using those. ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `&` which is used for expression and from markup you could call that method like `ngChange()` instead of `ngChange` only

**Markup**

```
  <select 
        ng-model="ngModel" ng-change="ngChange()"
        ng-options="option[optionId] as option[optionName] for option in options">
  </select>
```

**Code**

```
scope: {
   ngModel: '=',
   ngChange: '&'
}
```

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/92BaEB41GBYlwkHyEfB0?p=preview)

Comment: `&` or `@` is not working - `someFunction()` is not getting executed if used so.

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar try the way i suggested..change your code as i decteted..till then I'll create a plunkr for you

Comment: making it `ngChange()` in template is not working either.

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar could you look at the plunkr which I have added in the answer..

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: @pankaj-parkerHi, a follow up question, since I'm allowed to post only once per 90 minutes, I'm asking it here

http://plnkr.co/edit/fFSoLmPFDBfNc2oOczZr?p=preview
check this plunk,

in it, the argument being passed to `someFunction()` contains unexpected values, sometimes it is undefined, sometimes it has correct value

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/A8YDv0V8HldWh25GmMkW?p=preview , I think you wanted to do this

Comment: as I'm building a reusable directive, this `someModel` can be any model, can have different names, how can I make sure to reflect it in the template, as `someModel` from the directive usage code is same as  (or bound together ) the `someModel` in template code? (it  is, right ?)

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar yes you are correct..you could reuse this as reusable component

Comment: when I use `someOtherModel` as a model name instead of `someModel` , the code breaks (as the `someModel` in usage code is bound to `someModel` in template)

Comment: You shouldn't be worry about `ng-change` thing, It should be `ng-change="someFunction(someModel)"` instead of `ng-change="someFunction(someOtherModel)"` because in the end its just a parameter name which going to provide to controller no matter whatever it would be.. checkout this http://plnkr.co/edit/O1RrW7zJldKyuFJMwrid?p=preview

Comment: oh! Thanks!! :-) :-) :-) you're awesome!!

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar glad to help you..Look at the answer..which I gave on your other post

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar could you accept & upvote this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/a/32148907/2435473