# How to fix unexpected arguments passing from a function being on ng-change for select list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

http://plnkr.co/edit/fFSoLmPFDBfNc2oOczZr?p=preview

Directive code

```
.directive('inputSelect', function() {
        return {
          templateUrl: 'someTemplate.html',
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            ngChange: '&',
            options: '='
          }
        };
      })
```

Controller code

```
  $scope.someFunction = function(name) {
            console.log(name)
          };
  $scope.colors = [{
        name: 'black',
        shade: 'dark'
      }, {
        name: 'white',
        shade: 'light',
        notAnOption: true
      }, {
        name: 'red',
        shade: 'dark'
      }];
```

Template code

```
<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-change="ngChange()" 
  ng-options="option.name for option in options">
</select>
```

Code for directive usage

```
<input-select ng-model="someModel" ng-change="someFunction(someModel.name)" options="colors"></input-select>
```

So, the arguments being passed to `someFunction()` is being `undefined` or it contains correct value, the behaviour is unexpected and random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template should call a method by passing a parameter in JSON format like `ng-change="ngChange({someModel: ngModel})"` from directive

Make sure while calling function from directive you should pass parameter with the key should be function parameter name as here it is `someModel` and then pass the value like here its `ngModel`

**Markup**

```
<input-select ng-model="someModel" ng-change="someFunction(someModel)" options="colors"></input-select>
```

**Directive template**

```
<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-change="ngChange({someModel: ngModel})" 
  ng-options="option.name for option in options">
</select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EhsRFlFnKHSqBZfJ6DA5?p=preview)

Comment: Now, if I want to pass more than one parameter, to `someFunction()` , another parameter being some completely different model in the same controller, what should it be done ?

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar your template should have pass it..but in this case how could you think about more parameter..could you give me some example?

Comment: Now, again the problem with above plunk is, `differentModel` is the different model in the controller, and it can have other name like `someOtherDifferentModel`, in that case, the code breaks, what should be done ?

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar you made it bro..Thats awesome..you are quick learner

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar you have some misunderstanding about the passing method to directive and call function from the directive with parameter..I can't explain each and every thing here ,, you should go and watch this video https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding

Comment: The plunkr is updated with best working example :-)
Thanks a lot for everything! :-)